# Javascript: unable to submit form

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to use javascript (used within another program) to automate the submission of a form with the appropriate textboxes filled in. Using the simple page below, I can successfully fill out the text box using:

```
javascript:document.getElementsByName('UserIDValue')[0].value = "12345";
```

but can't seem to get anything to work that will actually submit the form. None of these attempts at solving it work: (By 'work' I mean have the same effect as if I clicked the Log In button.)

```
document.forms["MFALogInForm"].submit();
document.getElementsByName("LoginButton")[0].submit();
document.getElementById("MFALogInForm").submit();
document.forms[0].submit();
```

the code for the page I'm working with is below: The link to it is here: https://ppcplus.121fcu.org/Mobile/Features/Auth/MFA/MFALogin.aspx

```
<html><body>
<form id="MFALogInForm" name="MFALogInForm" method="post" action="MFALogin.aspx?__ufps=981699">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTTARGET" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="__EVENTARGUMENT" value="">
<script language=javascript><!--
function __doPostBack(target, argument){
  var theform = document.MFALogInForm
  theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = target
  theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = argument
  theform.submit()
}
// -->
</script>
<img id="RoofImage" src="/Mobile/Images/Current_HandheldDevice/Universal/1Pixel.gif" alt="Private PC" /><br />
<img id="LogoHeader_LogoImage" src="/Mobile/Images/Current_HandheldDevice/Universal/Logo.gif" /><br />

<font size="+1" color="#006D9B"><b>LOGIN</b></font><br>
<font size="-1"><b>USER ID</b></font><br>
<input name="UserIDValue"/><br>
<input name="LoginButton" type="submit" value="Log In"/><input name="ResetButton" type="submit" value="Reset"/><br>
</form></body></html>
```

Comment: `document.forms[0].submit();` works perfectly for me on the site you linked. Check the console for javascript exceptions, I suspect that the execution don't even gets to the line of code in question.

Comment: I dunno. I finally found something that worked. It was document.forms[0].elements["LoginButton"].click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
document.forms[0].elements["LoginButton"].click();
```

worked for me.